# I cannot understand this error in Pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am working on a project and I need well... a Database (MongoDB atlas) and I see while trying to send data I get this error :

```
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-00.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-01.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-02.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61fa067baedd893a84a4269d, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.e4dtu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.e4dtu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.e4dtu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.e4dtu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>
```

Comment: May be your machine or ip address is not allowed to access the database url and you need vpn to connect.

Comment: But I have configured the IP address

Comment: Oh i get it now... I was being an idiot i was running the code on replit instead of running it locally

Comment: Perhaps you could also post the line(s) of code that raised this error?

Comment: Oh I fixed that error

Comment: I have a different error now I dont understand that one

Comment: I was runing my code in replit and not on my local computer. Which was pretty dump from my side

Answer (score 0):

Well I was being an Idiot and running the code on Replit... Which ofc runs on a different computer whose IP address was not SET tp my Database. I now run it on my local computer and it is fine.